# Jmeter not able to iterate for more than one user after configuring proxy setting with firefox browser

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMeter, Actually i was testing PHP application with JMeter. I configured firefox browser proxy with port number with JMeter port number from Test Script Recorder's Global Settings. I have imported the JMeter Certificate inside firefox Certificate Manager. All configuration was fine. But when I clicked on Start button from Test Script Recorder, it was generating the test results but I am not able to run test results for more than one users. It is showing only one iteration. The Thread group number is not generating and showing one iteration result. How can I run test cases for more than one user after configuring the browser?

Answer (score 1):

The Test Script Recorder initially records the requests and generates results (by default) to see if correct requests are recorded or if they are some error in the requests.
To execute multiple times, you need to complete the recording first.

1. Complete your Recording.
2. Click on the Stop button in the test recorder.
3. Go to Thread group. Increase the number in the Number of Threads field.
4. Click on the Run button.
5. Then run the test and view the results in Tree Listener or whichever listener you prefer.

   Check if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to modify your threadgroup.  See http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html.

> By default, the thread group is configured to loop once through its
>   elements.